multiple definition of extern variable in c++
I have four file
main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "global.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=1;
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

screen.cpp
int i=2;

snake.cpp
int i=2;

global.h
extern int i;

I receive error of "multiple definition error of 'i' , first defined here".

The definition (in your case, int i = 2) should exist in exactly ONE source file within your project.   For example, in EITHER screen.cpp or snake.cpp,  NOT both.    Defining it in more than one source file means, as the error message, says, it is defined multiple times.  You might want to consider defining it in a separate source file (e.g. in a globals.cpp).

Note that the "int i=1;" in main is a definition for a different, local, variable that has no connection to the global one of the same name.

You have a definition of i in snake.cpp and you have a definition of the same variable in screen.cpp and you have a multiple definition error. Is it not obvious what you have to do? Remove one of the definitions.

Yes, you have multiple definitions, and you have narrowed down the cause nicely. (It would be even better if you reduced your main function to int main() {} since that is likely not mentioned in the full error message.) What's the question?

There is no clear question... If you want screen.cpp and snake.cpp to use the same variable (potentially also visible in main.cpp) maybe you could #include global, and not use extern. If you want both a local and the "extern" i variables, consider using (unnamed) namespaces to clarify which you use, and avoid collision / multiple definitions.
